# Get access to OpenCV GpuMat channels

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I am working on a raytracer. I wanted to optimize my code by saving data of each pixel in an OpenCV `Mat`, using GPU.

For now, I save pixel values in buffer `fb` which is a vector of three values (RGB):

```
__global__ void render(vec3 *fb, int max_x, int max_y, Camera **cam, Triangle *data, size_t n, )
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if ((i >= max_x) || (j >= max_y)) return;
    int pixel_index = j * max_x + i;
    float u = float(i) / float(max_x);
    float v = float(j) / float(max_y);
    Ray r = (*cam)->get_ray(u,v);
    fb[pixel_index] = color(r, data,n);
}
```

and then I save data in Mat on CPU:

```
for (int j = ny - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) 
    {
        size_t pixel_index = j * nx + i;
        int ir = int(255.99*fb[pixel_index].r());
        int ig = int(255.99*fb[pixel_index].g());
        int ib = int(255.99*fb[pixel_index].b());
        output.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[0] = (uchar)ib;
        output.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[1] = (uchar)ig;
        output.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[2] = (uchar)ir;
        //std::cout << ir << " " << ig << " " << ib << "\n";
    }
}
```

but it is a very slow process when I have a large pixel array. That why I want to use an OpenCV  `GpuMat` and save the data directly on the GPU.

The problem is that I can't really find an example of how I can save data in each channel of GPU Mat. Is it an easy way to do it, similar to saving data on the CPU?

Comment: `GpuMat` is just a wrapper around a device buffer to make working in opencv easier. You can let its constructor create one with its default allocator, or you can pass a device pointer to an already-allocated buffer as the `*data` argument along with dimension/stride/type info (highly recommended if using streams or multiple gpus). You can also interop with OpenGL using the `ogl::` namespace or via standard CUDA methods. For example, you could populate it directly by passing its buffer pointer into your kernel. Maybe you should explain more about how you hope to use it?

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#details). There it says

> no functions that return references to their data (because references on GPU are not valid for CPU)

The only way to access the data is through the `data`function. But the pointer can only be dereferenced in (cuda)kernel code. And there is no 
`at` function as far as I see. So you will have to calculate the offset from data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. They make me think how to do it in another way. I am not sure if it is the best solution to deal with it but it works and in my opinion is a quiet easy way to fill matrix on GPU.

1. Reserve memory on GPU for matrix

```
Mat output(ny, nx, CV_8UC3);
    const size_t numBytes = output.step * output.rows;
    unsigned char *d_output;
    cudaMalloc<unsigned char>(&d_output, numBytes);
```

2. Fill matrix on GPU

```
_global__ void render(vec3 *fb, int max_x, int max_y, Camera **cam, Triangle *data, size_t n, unsigned char* input, int step)
{

    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if ((i >= max_x) || (j >= max_y)) return;
    int pixel_index = j * max_x + i;
    int index = j * step + 3 * i;
    float u = float(i) / float(max_x);
    float v = float(j) / float(max_y);
    Ray r = (*cam)->get_ray(u,v);
    fb[pixel_index] = color(r, data,n);
    int ir = int(255.99*fb[pixel_index].r());
    int ig = int(255.99*fb[pixel_index].g());
    int ib = int(255.99*fb[pixel_index].b());


    input[index] = ib;
    input[index+1] = ig;
    input[index+2] = ir;


}
```

I will be grateful for any advice and comments to this code.

Comment: I do not like the first step. I think it is easier to use the GPUMat and get its' `data` and `step` info. Remember you have to free the device memory with `cudaFree`. The second steps looks good to me, as long as you can answer the following questions with yes: `fb`, `cam` and `data` point to device memory? `fb` is an linear array (without padding)?